# Render value without data-binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

In AngularJS, how can I render a value without 2-way data binding? One may want to do this for performance reasons, or even rendering a value at a given point in time.

**The following examples both use data binding:**

`<div>{{value}}</div>`

`<div data-ng-bind="value"></div>`

How do I render `value` **without any** data binding?

Comment: whats your input and output . plz explain

Comment: Your examples are actually one-way data binding (model changes -> view updates).  `ng-model` gives you two-way data binding: model changes -> view updates, view changes -> model updates.

Comment: updated. sorry i meant I want no data-binding at all

Comment: I don't think this question is terrible or deserved a downvote.  It's actually really common to want to disable data binding to prevent unnecessary watches.

Comment: @OverZealous if this question is about disabling data binding then it's a duplicate because i have asked that question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240168/genuinely-stop-a-element-from-binding-unbind-an-element-angularjs

Comment: UPDATE: anyone reading this article will probaly find this video extremely useful. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyYpHIOrk_Y

Answer (score 140, accepted):

**Angular 1.3+**

In 1.3, Angular has supported this using the following syntax.

```
<div>{{::message}}</div>
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043072/1907358).

---

**Angular 1.2 and below**

This is simple and doesn't need a plugin. Check this out.

This small directive will easily accomplish what you are trying to achieve

```
app.directive('bindOnce', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function( $scope ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $scope.$destroy();
            }, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

You can bind once like this

```
<div bind-once>I bind once - {{message}}</div>
```

You can bind like normal

```
<div ng-bind="message" bind-once></div>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fffnb/**

Some of you may be using angular batarang, and as mentioned in the comments if you use this directive the element still shows as binding when it is not, I am pretty sure this has something to do with the classes that are attached to the element so try this, it should work *(not tested)*. Let me know in the comments if it worked for you.

```
app.directive('bindOnce', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function( $scope, $element ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $scope.$destroy();
                $element.removeClass('ng-binding ng-scope');
            }, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

[@x0b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790333/angular-js-render-value-without-data-binding/18791503?noredirect=1#comment35565641_18791503): If you have OCD and you want to remove the empty `class` attribute do this

```
!$element.attr('class') && $element.removeAttr('class')
```

Comment: im yet to test the plugin, but I would assume the AngularJS chrome tools would not show the bind-once element as a binding, where as your example does. Interesting approach tho, I will test both approaches soon.

Comment: See this - it shows both as bindings https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14037764/Development/stackoverflow/angular/bindings-dev-tools.PNG

Comment: Without a doubt that is because if the ng-binding class that you can easily remove

Comment: In the setTimeout remove the ng-binding and ng-scope classes

Comment: This is great and much simpler than the bindonce plugin. I added an ability to wait for a condition before destroying the scope and it's really helpful. thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `$timeout` to make it testable?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I can't see any advantages using `$timeout`, it will be doing more operations that I don't think are needed, of course you can do though, if you wish

Comment: For those who want to remove a redundant empty class attribute then add this:

if ($element.attr('class') === '') {
   $element.removeAttr('class');
}

Comment: @x0b cheers, I've done that before, it does get annoying I'll add a reference in the answer.

Comment: How does this work for deferred objects on a scope? The bind-once is destroying the scope before the property I want to bind-once is resolved.

Comment: @SirTophamHatt that defeats the object of "bind once", if your property isn't resolved then the first bound value will be undefined, you're going to need a different solution for a different problem

Comment: @Connor I disagree. For example, I'm receiving a video object ($scope.video) from a REST API and I want one-time binding of the video title ($scope.video.title). Even if I resolve the promise BEFORE adding it to the scope in the controller, I still have to declare ng-bind="video.title" bind-once on the DOM. Now, before the promise gets resolved, video.title is undefined, and the scope gets destroyed before video.title is defined. A solution I have for this is to wrap the elements in some type of loading/init flag, ng-if="someLoadingFlag", but it's a poor pattern.

Comment: @Connor - the "$scope.$destroy" will not remove the $watch (on angular 1.2). Any ideas how this could be fixed? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400422/angularjs-scope-destroy-doesnt-remove-watchers

Comment: After struggling for a while, I made a Question regarding the Batarang thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012004/angular-one-way-data-binding-not-working/32012006#32012006

Answer (score 49):

It looks like Angular 1.3 (starting with beta 10) has one-time binding built in:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

> One-time binding
>
> An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression.
>   One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable,
>   which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a
>   non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).

Comment: This answer again and again. I can't praise you enough Karl! I highly recommend the agressive usage of this feature wherever it makes sense.

Comment: Wow I am really glad I scrolled down. I'm going to ask Connor to reference this in his accepted answer.

Comment: I have a table / list with 2000 lines and using the one-time-binding operator my app gets extremely slow when first showing / rendering the list. So slow, that the browser asks me two or three times if I want to stop executing the script!

Comment: @billy-g Can you post a jsfiddle or plunker illustrating the issue?

Comment: @James Daily: Here is the "normal" case http://plnkr.co/edit/rCRP0T5fSgNIllx7F27y and here the "one-time expression" case http://plnkr.co/edit/Rd5VBVjkcX3sTJYGypUr but... I can not reproduce it there. Anyway, it isn't faster with the "one-time expression" and I have to do more investigation to find why it happens in my environment (I use 1.3 beta 18 of angularjs)

Answer (score 20):

Use the [bindonce module](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce).  You'll need to include the JS file and add it as a dependency to your app module:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['pasvaz.bindonce']);
```

This library allows you to render items that are bound only once — when they are first initialized.  Any further updates to those values will be ignored.  It's a great way to reduce the number of watches on the page for things that won't change after they are rendered.

Usage example:

```
<div bo-text="value"></div>
```

When used like this, the property under `value` will be set once it is available, but then the watch will be disabled.

Comment: I was about to write an answer "write your own directive ...", but it looks like someone has already done that for us, nice.

Comment: Bindonce is useful enough that it could be included as a built-in optional library, like `$resource`.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, however I was expecting something like this to be built into angular!

Answer (score 7):

Comparison between @OverZealous and @Connor answers :

With the traditional ngRepeat of angular : 15s for 2000 rows and 420mo of RAM ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jwrHVb?p=preview))

With ngRepeat and the module of @OverZealous : 7s for 2000 rows and 240mo of RAM([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0DGOrk?p=preview))

With ngRepeat and the directive of @Connor : 8s for 2000 rows and 500mo of RAM ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SDn0LT18VwHhhA67wMfX?p=preview))

I made my tests with Google Chrome 32.

Comment: Would be nice to also have `angular-once` compared. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe : I planned to do the tests when a stable build of AngularJS 1.3 be published.

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to include [`angular-once`](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once) package (I've posted it as an alternative option here).

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, there is [`angular-once`](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once) package:

> If you use AngularJS, have performance issues and need to display lots
>   of readonly data, this project is for you!

`angular-once` was actually inspired by `bindonce` and provides similar `once-*` attributes:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
      <a once-href="user.profileUrl" once-text="user.name"></a>
        <a once-href="user.profileUrl"><img once-src="user.avatarUrl"></a>
        <div once-class="{'formatted': user.description}" once-bind="user.description"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```