# Is binding to a function faster than binding to a property in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to improve performance on an angularJS app. my colleague told me that this....

`<div ng-bind="getValue()"></div>`   **//where this returns 'value'**

Is less performant than this...

```
<div ng-bind="value"></div>
```

Is this true? If so why?

Comment: If `getValue()` is simply `return value;` there'd be very little difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this only makes sense if it is one way binding. as it is a function and you don't need to watch/observe the changes might have some benefits but then there is a binding called one-way binding in ng. It would be wiser if you use it.

Edit: it is called one-time binding and only available AngularJS 1.3. But there is [a good SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790333/angular-js-render-value-without-data-binding) for it and alternative approach for 1.2, also have a very simple comparison .

Answer (score 0):

If your function simply return a value, and doesn't accept any parameters, then it's not a good practice to to so: let's say you want to change that value later on, as a result of some function or user action.