# Angularjs - $scope.$destroy doesn't remove watchers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to figure out how to create my own "one time binding", for Angularjs <= 1.2.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790333/render-value-without-data-binding), describing how to create your own bindOnce directive. I do see that when using the following directive:

```
    app.directive('bindOnce', function() {
    return {
            scope: true,
            link: function( $scope ) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $scope.$destroy();
                }, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Data is binded once. **But**, I can see that the $$watchers is still on. Take a look at the following [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wufanu/3/edit?html,js,console,output) - running the commented watcher count code on the console will reveal that the watchers are still alive.

**EDIT**: for some reason, when using the same directive with angular 1.3, the watcher count dod changed to be 0!!!

Comment: Have you tried using $timeout instead of setTimeout?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce?

Comment: @JonSnow: I did, it does not change anything. Regarding "github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce" - it does the work. I wanted to understand what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: @james you are correct, bindonce did the trick, although I was looking for a simpler solution. tnx!

Answer (score -1):

Use the `cleanup` function to remove watchers:

```
function cleanup(element) 
  { 
  element.off().removeData();

  var injector = currentSpec.$injector;

  element.$injector = null;

  // clean up jquery's fragment cache
  angular.forEach(angular.element.fragments, function(val, key) {
    delete angular.element.fragments[key];
  });

  angular.forEach(angular.callbacks, function(val, key) 
    {
    delete angular.callbacks[key];
    });

  angular.callbacks.counter = 0;
  }
```

Use a self-destructing service as a simple bind once:

```
function onetime()
  {
  /*...*/
  onetime = Function;
  }

angular.module('myApp').constant('bindonce', onetime);

angular.module('myApp').controller('foo', function($bindonce){
  this.$inject = '$bindonce';
  $scope.mybind = $bindonce();
}
```

Use the migration guide for reference to find breaking changes:

**References**

- [testabilityPatch.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/helpers/testabilityPatch.js)
- [angular-mocks.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide: Migration from Previous Versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

Comment: Please note that my question specifically mentioned I am seeking for a solution using Angular 1.2.X. The {{::attr}} is for Angular 1.3+