# i need React databinding (Arr push after data refresh)

Tags: reactjs

I am faced with the problem

web page is to react with the signal.

Signal does not regularly.

my Scenarios (Arr data push after refresh)

It does not give any one event

Because I can not use. setState funciton

i think javascript function call for react databind refresh

Because the data binding, you use the following dataRefresh() functions.

I know code is incorrect.

I've written code like the following:

```
var dataArr = [{
  key : '1',
  text : "hello1",
  title: "title1"
},
{
  key : '2',
  text : "hello2",
  title: "title2"
},
{
  key : '3',
  text : "hello3",
  title: "title3"
}
];

var Repeat = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
    var data = this.props.items;
    return(
        <PanelGroup accordion >
           { data.map(function(item){
            return(
              <Panel header={item.title} eventKey={item.key} >
                {item.text}
              </Panel>
              );
           })}
        </PanelGroup>
      );
  }

});

function startReact(){
  React.render(
    <div>
    <Repeat items={ dataArr }/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('content')
    );
}

startReact();

function dataRefresh(){
  dataArr.push({
    key : '4',
    text : "hello4",
    title: "title4"
  });

  startReact();
}

setTimeout("dataChange()",3000);
```

It is the question.

1. I need to have an idea that can solve the problem.
2. Advice is required.

Comment: You are basically doing it right, read this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setprops I guess your error here is that you do a setTimeout on `dataChange()`, but there is no such function? I guess you meant `dataRefresh`? Also, don't use setTimeout with strings, use a function as suggested by @mohamedrias

Comment: @Simon thank you sir , Links have been a great help to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render value without data-binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790333/render-value-without-data-binding)

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea. When you have new data use setState so it will update/rerender your view automatically that's the point of react.

Bind your update to a function that update the state not directly to the render.

Here is an example very easy it explain how to update your state when the user is clicking on some button:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

So for your instead of handling a user action you'll set an handler that is called when you have new data.

I hope it's clear

Comment: Tell us an example or sample site

Comment: user clicks an event is an example of data changes.
i want javascript function call data changes

Comment: this is the same thing but in your case you call the handler with a "javascript function" :)

Answer (score 0):

To go in React way, you must use state instead of that above method.

Use `getInitialState` to point to the global `dataArr` and then use `setState` to update the state.

Even I would suggest putting dataArr in the base component holding the child components. This will avoid polluting the global namespace as well.

Inside your setTimeout, avoid using string. instead wrap it inside a function like below:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   dataChange();
}, 3000);
```

So the code will become:

```
var Repeater = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() { 
        return {
           data: dataArr
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
              // update the dataArr
              // Instead of calling dataChange gloabl method, I would put it inside the base component and call this.updateData();
             // this.setState({data: dataArr});
       }.bind(this),3000);
    },

    updateData: function() {
           // increment the array and call 
           this.setState({data: dataArr});

    },
    render : function() {
             return (
                 <div>
                    <Repeat items={ this.state.data}/>
                 </div>
             );
    }
});
```

The below code will become:

```
function startReact(){
  React.render(<Repeater />,
    document.getElementById('content')
    );
}
```

Comment: `To go in React way, you must use state instead of that above method.` that's not true because he's updating a root component. He's doing it the correct way, see here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setprops I guess his problem is that he's using a string in setTimeout and didn't  notice that he misspelled the function name.

Comment: If you check the method dataRefresh(), OP is rendering the view by calling startReact() in the timeout. It's not necessary. In react, the root element will persist data in the states and if it has to share data among child components will use props to propagate data

Comment: startReact() is just calling React.render, which is the correct way to either render a new root component, or update an already mounted one, please read the link I posted. He probably just shouldn't have named it 'startReact', but simply 'renderReact' or something.