# Angular: One way data-binding not working

Tags: angularjs

This is driving me crazy.

I have a `log` filter.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('log', [function() {
  return function(content) {
    console.log(content);
    return content;
  };
}]);
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.myValue = 'Test';
```

And in my view:

```
{{::myValue | log}}
```

And every time the `$digest` cycle is called, `myValue` gets loggued 2 times, which **shouldn't** because of [one-way-data-binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).

It has been 3 hours I stuck on this. I have been trying to reproduce in a plunker, without success. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790333/render-value-without-data-binding), I found the culprit after few hours.

It was [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en), now removed from my Chrome **forever**.