# There is a way to update view without use Two way bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a way to update a value in object and my view (HTML) display the new value without use two way bind with Angular 1.5.3?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790333/render-value-without-data-binding

Comment: @Chinni Yeah. I already saw this thread. But my case I something different between because I need to update in view but only when my model change. So If I really understand angular-once or bindOnce directive just update one time (at DOM creation) and no more. Is it right?

Comment: @LeonanLuppi yeah that's correct, so you need a one-way binding from controller to view but not the other way around? That's just standard [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

Comment: @NexusDuck But standard ng-bind makes watcher I'm trying to avoid watcher.

Comment: @LeonanLuppi Can you give an example of what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: @Leonan Luppi: If you want to change the DOM value once the value in controller changes without two way bind, then you can go ahead with native JS using `document.getElementById()` function to update the DOM from controller.

Comment: @NexusDuck http://jsfiddle.net/988DP/508/

Comment: @NexusDuck image that I have many $scope.obj . This is generate many watchers in my app.

Comment: angular 1.5 introduced one-way binding with the `<` scope expression https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

Comment: @Daniel_L yeah but how can I use in scope ? I think this is just for directive scope definitions. Following my example: http://jsfiddle.net/988DP/508/ how can I use ?

Comment: @LeonanLuppi hard to say without a concrete example and no code.

Comment: @Daniel_L here it's a concrete example: http://jsfiddle.net/988DP/508/

Comment: @LeonanLuppi I updated my answer with what I think you need

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need a one-way bind from your controller to your view. If so, you can just use [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

E.g.

`{{ctrl.myName}}` or `<span ng-bind="ctrl.myName"></span>`

If you want a one-time bind, this was introduced in angular 1.3:

E.g.:

`{{::ctrl.myName}}` binds `myName` once, future changes to it won't be picked up