# AngularJS set Bootstrap glyphicon Title

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my form page I have one Bootstrap glyphicon

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" title="" style="float:right; top:4px;"></i>
```

I want to set the value of `ng-model="organization.orgName"` inside `title=""` of the Bootstrap glyphicon. So that I can see the info when I am doing mouse over on this icon.

So please help me how can I do this.
I am using AngularJS and Bootstrap v3.3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is pretty simple, just put the variable in [angular expresion (interpolation)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) for title ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/HN13uByCxyKzE7m8Y13s?p=preview)):

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$scope.title = 'Info';
```

**HTML:**

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" title="{{myTitle}}"></i>
```

---

*If you are using angular version >= 1.3 [you can disable the two way data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790333/render-value-without-data-binding) for better performance with this syntax: `title="{{::myTitle}}"`*