# AngularJS cache service for in-line .svg files (wrapping $http with promises)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, svg, angular-promise

I have implemented an angular `<svgimg src="file">` directive to load .svg images inline, the link function uses $http to load the file which is then parsed to add and remove tags. The result is inline `<svg>` which can be coloured and sized with css.

This works fine, but since my app will have *loads* of small images this solution is not very efficient because angular calls the service multiple times per digest - which means the loading/parsing process is performed 100's of times ($http cache helped).

I am trying to replace the `$http.get()` part of the directive with a caching service.

The cache service maintains a list of already-loaded files and provides the ready-to-inject version.

My problem is in implementing the promises....

The `app.directive()` link function does:

```
link: function( scope, element, attrs ){
    var promise= svgService.get( svgFilename );  // was: $http.get(...)
    promise.then( 
        function(data){
            // sort injected attribs and then...
            element.replaceWith(data);
        },
        function(data){ /* error stuff */ } 
    );
};
```

which appears to be fine.

The service function is along the lines of:

```
app.service('svgCacheService', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http){
    this.get=function( srcfile ){
        var deferred= $q.defer();

        if( srcfile in cache is loaded ){
            deferred.resolve( cache[srcfile] );
            return deferred.promise;        // ok, no problem with this
        }else{
            if( srcfile in cache marked as 'loading' ){
                // file is marked in cache, but is waiting for $http
                return SOME_PROMISE;        // tried allsorts, no luck yet :(
            }else{
                // file not in cache
                cache[srcfile]='loading';   // new cache entry, marked 'loading' 
                $http.get( srcfile )
                .success( function(data){
                    // xml parsing etc. goes in here
                    cache[srcfile]= data;

                    // how to resolve waiting promises waiting on 'loading'???

                    deferred.resolve( cache[srcfile] );
                    return deferred.promise;   // this caller is ok
                }
                .error( ... error stuff ... )
            }
        }
    }
```

This sort-of works, but only actually loads a few images (some are used multiple times on a page and the odd one does appear) - I *think* the problem seems to be that the SOME_PROMISE's issued in the case of 'cache is loading' are not resolved.

I have tried adding the `deferred` object in the cache and returning that to each caller, but it makes no difference.

**Questions:**

I'm guessing that I need to keep track of lots of separate promises... do I need to keep an array of SOME_PROMISE in the cache and then resolve them all when the $http succeeds ?

Generally, can you only return a given promise instance to one caller ?

Any hints/tips/links would be much appreciated... thanks.

Comment: Total size of all SVG files? SVGs are tiny compared to an image (read: Megabytes), I'd cache ALL SVG in browser (send the entire collection in ZIP or LZString)

Comment: There's only about 250k in ~200 .svg files... I did think about pre-processing them but want to leave it to the client to cook up more images whenever they want. My caching is so I only have to process them once to insert into the DOM so css can do its stuff.

Comment: Have you tried the [one time binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183095/angularjs-really-slow-at-rendering-with-about-2000-elements) to fix the loading/parsing? Try to fix the root cause first.

Comment: one time binding does look interesting... I'll see if we can use the newer version of angular - thanks.